# Should Kotlin test classes be internal?

Tags: testing, kotlin

When you generate a test class for a given class in IntelliJ, say `class Foo`, it will generate a test class `internal class FooTest`. Why does it default to an `internal class`? What's the advantage of using internal classes for test classes?

The way I was generating test classes is: put cursor on the class name `Foo`, press `Option/Alt`+`Enter`, select "Create Test".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `internal` visibility means that it can be accessed by other classes in the same module. This is the closest Kotlin has to Java's default 'package-private' which also makes sense for tests written in Java.

Using `private` is more restrictive making it so that test classes can reuse each other which can be useful some times. There really shouldn't be a use for public test classes, unless they're global test helpers which would be the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Your explanation makes no sense. I mean no matter what visibility a test class has it will never be visible to any class outside the module it is defined. Not only module it is defined but it will only be visible inside the "unitTest" package.

Answer (score 0):

Internal is a new modifier available in Kotlin that’s not there in Java.
Setting a declaration as internal means that it’ll be available in the same module only.
By module in Kotlin, we mean a group of files that are compiled together.

```
internal class A {
}

internal val x = 0
```

These won’t be visible outside the current module.
Internal Modifiers is useful when you need to hide specific library implementations from the users.
This wasn’t possible using the package-private visibility in Java.